# How can i make a query in mongodb that returns the most repeated value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I hope you can help me.

I have 3 models: Appointment, User, Branch

I am trying to do a query like this:

```js
getCitasCliente: async ( req, res = response ) => {

    const idCliente = req.params.idCliente;
    // const idSucursal = req.params.idSucursal;

    const citas = await Cita
        .find({idCliente}, 'idCliente nombreCliente tipoCita idSucursal idAdmin')


     res.json({
         status: 'success',
         citas
     })
 }
```

This returns these results to me:

```json
{
    "status": "success",
    "citas": [
        {
            "idCliente": "5ed93644e5c3f97547d3e584",
            "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
            "_id": "5ef37c3fa57fs245f01c5b36",
            "tipoCita": "sucursal",
            "idSucursal": "5ef2cc1da46fa045f01c5b31",
            "idAdmin": "5ef2c37ea46fa045f01c5b30"
        },
        {
            "idCliente": "5ed93646e5c3f97547d3e584",
            "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
            "_id": "5ef52fa0ad04ea666d13301c",
            "tipoCita": "sucursal",
            "idSucursal": "5ef24cf4e46f754236a1526a",
            "idAdmin": "5ebf0e41c2e46f17b8c1f963"
        },
        {
            "idCliente": "5ed93676e5c3f97547d3e584",
            "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
            "_id": "5ef53d1aad07la666d13301e",
            "tipoCita": "domicilio",
            "idSucursal": "5ef24cf4e19f754236a1526a",
            "idAdmin": "5ebf0e41c2e43f17b8c1f963"
        },
        {
            "idCliente": "5ed936465e5c3f97547d3e584",
            "nombreCliente": "Eduardo castañeda ",
            "_id": "5eff75c88434707ba223cb3a",
            "tipoCita": "sucursal",
            "idSucursal": "5ef2cc1da57fa185f01c5b31",
            "idAdmin": "5ef2c37ea57fa043f01c5b30"
        },
    ]
}
```

In my database there are several branches, I am trying to make a query that brings me the documents of the most repeated idSucursal of my database, Do you know a way to do this?

Thank you very much for your help!